# Error in setting an Adapter in RecyclerView and Cardview Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-cardview

My Application has an error in setting an adapter in my recyclerView. I implemented all the methods and look at my java class where the adapter is but i can't figure where are my errors. I even rewrite my codes but i still get the same error everytime I run the application. The logcat bring me to my MainActivity.java where i'm setting my adapter.  Take a look.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        List<Data_Reminder> data = fill_with_data();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reminder_recyclerview);
        recycler_reminder adapter = new recycler_reminder(data, getApplication());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

public List<Data_Reminder> fill_with_data() {

        List<Data_Reminder> data = new ArrayList<>();

        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Batman vs Superman", "Following the destruction of Metropolis, Batman embarks on a personal vendetta against Superman ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("X-Men: Apocalypse", "X-Men: Apocalypse is an upcoming American superhero film based on the X-Men characters that appear in Marvel Comics ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Captain America: Civil War", "A feud between Captain America and Iron Man leaves the Avengers in turmoil.  ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Kung Fu Panda 3", "After reuniting with his long-lost father, Po  must train a village of pandas", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Warcraft", "Fleeing their dying home to colonize another, fearsome orc warriors invade the peaceful realm of Azeroth. ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Alice in Wonderland", "Alice in Wonderland: Through the Looking Glass ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));

        return data;
    }
}
```

**fragment_blank.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/reminder_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

**Data_Reminder.java**

```
public class Data_Reminder {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public int imageId;

    Data_Reminder(String name, String description, int imageId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

}
```

**recycler_reminder.java**

```
public class recycler_reminder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<view_holder> {

    List<Data_Reminder> list = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;

    public recycler_reminder(List<Data_Reminder> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public view_holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_reminder, parent, false);
        view_holder holder = new view_holder(v);
        return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(view_holder holder, int position) {

        //Use the provided View Holder on the onCreateViewHolder method to populate the current row on the RecyclerView
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).name);
        holder.description.setText(list.get(position).description);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).imageId);

        //animate(holder);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will display
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    // Insert a new item to the RecyclerView on a predefined position
    public void insert(int position, Data_Reminder data) {
        list.add(position, data);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    // Remove a RecyclerView item containing a specified Data object
    public void remove(Data_Reminder data) {
        int position = list.indexOf(data);
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

}
```

Here is my **logcat**

```
07-12 00:50:54.394 27684-27684/application.cedie.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: application.cedie.myapplication, PID: 27684
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{application.cedie.myapplication/application.cedie.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:949)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:744)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at application.cedie.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:949) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:744)
```

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: Set your LayoutManager BEFORE you setAdapter

Comment: Still getting the error @Mark Keen

Comment: is your recyclerView inside the activity or fragment, in the above xml I notice that the name of the xml is fragment_blank and you have your code initialization in main activity. please check again

Comment: i have my recyclerView in a fragment. @SaravInfern

Comment: then the above initialization for your recycler view is incorrect,it will always throw null pointer exception. If you are using recycler view from a fragment please attach the fragment to your  activity and initialize like this  `RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.reminder_recyclerview);` where fragementView is the fragment layout

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand @SaravInfern

Comment: you must have your recyclerview inside activity_main.xml,in order to initialize inside activity, if you want to intialize inside a fragment you must inflate the fragment in your activity and initialize it properly, please look into the example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357571/recyclerview-activity-to-fragment

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem by moving this codes into my BlankFragment.java

```
List<Data_Reminder> data = fill_with_data();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reminder_recyclerview);
        recycler_reminder adapter = new recycler_reminder(data, getApplication());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

public List<Data_Reminder> fill_with_data() {

        List<Data_Reminder> data = new ArrayList<>();

        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Batman vs Superman", "Following the destruction of Metropolis, Batman embarks on a personal vendetta against Superman ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("X-Men: Apocalypse", "X-Men: Apocalypse is an upcoming American superhero film based on the X-Men characters that appear in Marvel Comics ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Captain America: Civil War", "A feud between Captain America and Iron Man leaves the Avengers in turmoil.  ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Kung Fu Panda 3", "After reuniting with his long-lost father, Po  must train a village of pandas", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Warcraft", "Fleeing their dying home to colonize another, fearsome orc warriors invade the peaceful realm of Azeroth. ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data_Reminder("Alice in Wonderland", "Alice in Wonderland: Through the Looking Glass ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));

        return data;
    }
```

this is in the onCreateView() method in my new **BlankFrament.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    // 1. get a reference to recyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reminder_recyclerview);

    // 2. set layoutManger
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    // 3. create an adapter
    List<Data_Reminder> data = fill_with_data();
    recycler_reminder adapter = new recycler_reminder(data, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

public List<Data_Reminder> fill_with_data() {

    List<Data_Reminder> data = new ArrayList<>();

    data.add(new Data_Reminder("Batman vs Superman", "Following the destruction of Metropolis, Batman embarks on a personal vendetta against Superman ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
    data.add(new Data_Reminder("X-Men: Apocalypse", "X-Men: Apocalypse is an upcoming American superhero film based on the X-Men characters that appear in Marvel Comics ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
    data.add(new Data_Reminder("Captain America: Civil War", "A feud between Captain America and Iron Man leaves the Avengers in turmoil.  ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
    data.add(new Data_Reminder("Kung Fu Panda 3", "After reuniting with his long-lost father, Po  must train a village of pandas", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
    data.add(new Data_Reminder("Warcraft", "Fleeing their dying home to colonize another, fearsome orc warriors invade the peaceful realm of Azeroth. ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
    data.add(new Data_Reminder("Alice in Wonderland", "Alice in Wonderland: Through the Looking Glass ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));

    return data;
}
```