# ViewPager2 doesn't show Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, adapter, android-viewpager2

I am trying to implement ViewPager2 in my application and this is not the first time I am doing it but now it is not working.

I've been trying to find a solution for a couple of hours and trying different options but still - the fragments don't show up.
ViewPager2 is displaying correctly - I checked this by changing its background color.

I'm using the [OneUI 2.4.0](https://github.com/OneUIProject/OneUI-Design-Library) library - but I've tested this library before and everything worked, and now it won't.

**ViewPager2 Adapter**

```
public class MainViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    public MainViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MainFragment();
            case 1:
                return new NewsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ProfileFragment();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**MainFragment.java** (other fragments code looks the same)

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    View mRootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, true);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("MainFragment", "Initialized"); // I don't see that in logcat
    }
}
```

**fragment_main.xml** (Other fragments have similar layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<de.dlyt.yanndroid.oneui.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/main_page"
        android:textColor="@color/sesl_primary_text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</de.dlyt.yanndroid.oneui.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ToolbarLayout mToolbarLayout;
    private ViewPager2 mViewPager;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private MainViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialize();
        setup();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mToolbarLayout = (ToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.mToolbarLayout);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager2) findViewById(R.id.mMainPager);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.mMainTabLayout);
    }

    private void setup() {
        viewPagerAdapter = new MainViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
   }
```

And the problem is just that i don't see my fragments in ViewPager2.

Comment: can you please try with false like this

"mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);"

Comment: @SolankiZeel Thanks for the reply - I changed ```attachToRoot = false``` but the fragments still do not appear

Comment: try to return 0 instead of null with previous changes false. so we can get the idea that the adapter is fine

Edit: 

```return mRootView instead of
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);```

Comment: Your welcome @thewolf1119, I posted it as an answer vote it and check the mark. It helps others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [super.onCreateView in Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729330/super-oncreateview-in-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

try to

`return mRootView`

instead of

`return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Your code could be a bit more explained and why it did not work

Answer (score 0):

The place where you went wrong was when you did not add the layout to the root. The problem is this:

```java
return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

but, you r not using your view right? You are using the default view which is just empty. So, to solve it, you need to pass it your view instead of that. So, return your view like this:

```java
return mRootView;
```